# mistake while instaling percona

Tags: ubuntu, percona

I use this commands

```
wget https://repo.percona.com/apt/percona-release_0.1-4.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb
dpkg -i percona-release_0.1-4.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb
```

sudo apt-get update
and got this mistake

```
N: Ignoring file 'percona-release_0.1-4.xenial_all.deb.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'percona-release_0.1-4.xenial_all.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I use https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/installation/apt_repo.html tutorial and virtual env. Where is the mistake and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The output shows that you have left the Percona release  `.deb` file inside `/etc/apt.sources.d` - the directory gets scanned for files.
Move it out of that folder to somewhere else and the message about the Percona release will disappear.

The error that you have relates to a PPA that you have installed (unrelated to the Percona repository). You can find information about [how you can remove it](https://askubuntu.com/a/310), one of the options being `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa`